# Spring data jpa findByDate is always returning an empty list

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, spring-data

I'm using in my application spring-data-jpa 1.9.2, mysql-connector 5.1 and hibernate 4.3.11 Final.

My Order class has a "creation" attribute of type date.

```
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private java.util.Date creation;
}
```

In my JpaRepository I have these two methods to get the orders by date:

```
List<Order> findByCreation(Date date);
@Query("select o from Order o where o.creation = ?1")
List<Order> findByCreation2(Date date);
```

I'm not having an exception, but always an empty list, this can help you understand:

```
Date date = new Date();
Order order = new Order(date);
orderRepository.save(order);
Date creationFromDB = orderRepository.findOne(1L).getCreation();
System.out.println("eq? : "+ creationFromDB.equals(order.getCreation()));
List<Order> ods = orderRepository.findByCreation(creationFromDB);
List<Order> ods2 = orderRepository.findByCreation2(creationFromDB;
System.out.println("\n ods.size: " + ods.size() +", ods2.size: "+ods2.size());
```

The output is :

```
eq? : true
ods.size: 0, ods2.size: 0
```

**NOTE**

The select request had executed correctly and twice:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select order0_.id as id2_4_, order0_.creation as creation3_4_ from Orders order0_ where order0_.creation=?
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you generate your db scheme? Have you tried to generate it?

If it is possible to generate (with drop), set following property in your application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Potentially you have different data types (e.g. date vs. datetime) in you DB and used by spring data. I've recreated your project, and everithing worked fine whith H2 and MySQL.

EDIT:

Try to update your column description as follows:

```
@Column(name = "creation", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP(6)")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creation;
```

There might be different precisions. See my code:

Order class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Ordr")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "creation", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP(6)")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creation;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Test bean class.

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        Date date = new Date();

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setId(1L);
        order.setCreation(date);

        orderRepository.save(order);

        Date creationFromDB = orderRepository.findOne(1L).getCreation();

        System.out.println("eq? : "+ new Date(creationFromDB.getTime()).equals(order.getCreation()));
        List<Order> ods = orderRepository.findByCreation(creationFromDB);
        List<Order> ods2 = orderRepository.findByCreation2(creationFromDB);
        System.out.println("\n ods.size: " + ods.size() +", ods2.size: "+ods2.size());

    }
}
```

Result:
    eq? : true
    ods.size: 1, ods2.size: 1

DB query:

```
mysql> select * from ordr;
+----+----------------------------+
| id | creation                   |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | 2016-08-03 15:15:12.386000 |
+----+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: of course I'm generating the scheme, and it's also create-drop. NOTE that my creation attribute is of type java.util.date.

Comment: Is it possible to use newer version of hibernate? Do you use spring-boot?

Comment: See my update. Added my solution, I have expected result. Please check if that helps.

Comment: I think that the issue was in the database column type, looks like it was a datetime type so the `columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP(6)"` fixed the thing. Thank you.

Comment: It could be, by default there is different precision stored in DB than used in java.util.Date implementation. It is stored without milliseconds so if you query values with newDate() with "eq" condition it is very likely that you will not find anything.

Comment: Exactly! that's what I thought of too.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I assume you are using java.util.Date. If so, use the following in the entity:

```
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 private Date creation;
```

if your column in the database is defined to be of type timestamp. If you are using pure date part in the column use `TemporalType.DATE`.

This is not required if you are using `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: I have changed my column type to java.sql.Date and it's working. Thank you.

Comment: But the problem is that I can't save the time, I've tried sql.Timestamp but still getting the same problem above.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Nope. Same exact problem.

Comment: You said you're using `java.sql.Date`. Have you changed the code you posted above accordingly? I mean the code saving the `order` instance.

Comment: of course and it worked with sql.Date but the date is stored in this format : yyyy-mm-dd and I want it to be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, so I tried using sql.Timestamp but I got the same old problem (can't find by date).

Comment: You better post the implementation of the method `findByCreation()` method.

Comment: I'm using the spring-data JpaRepository (I didn't implement it), don't worry about the implementation, I'm sure that the issue is in types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119001/discussion-between-rached-anis-and-ujulu).

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong:

1. You need describe "creation" property

   @Column(name = "db_column_name")
   private Date creation;
2. I recomennded use Timestamp in class and in DB too. Timestamp more useful.

I hope to help

Comment: I've got the same problem with Timestamp.