# Java.Util.Date Query Problem with JPA and Hibernates Binding Parameter

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm currently working with Springboot. now I want to query data by Java.util.date via JpaRepository and I have the following code in my interface.

```
List<MyEnity> findByDate(Date date);
```

I use Java.util.date and I have a personal reason that I couldn't change to java.time. I've ensured that
MyEntity Class in date field has TemporalType.DATE like this

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) private Date date;
```

and also the date field in MySQL is also **date** type

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiAaY.png)
I tried to use the `findByDate(Date date)` method above and the **date** paramter in the method is obviously exist in my database but I always get an Empty List...

The other methods like `findByName(String name)` or `findAll()` work just fine.

I've tried to log the SQL statement from hibernate and I found that the binding parameter [DATE] might be in a different format? in my db is 'yyyy-mm-dd'

here is a log where I query with id and date. and at the bottom of the log I notice that the Id is binded with query statement, but date won't

```
    2563-04-10 12:18:54.649 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.d.a.ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener - Condition evaluation unchanged
2563-04-10 12:19:03.241 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/api/productionplan] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2563-04-10 12:19:03.282 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2563-04-10 12:19:03.307 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 8 ms
2563-04-10 12:19:03.346 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        planibtout0_.planibtoutid as planibto1_23_,
        planibtout0_.ibtqty as ibtqty2_23_,
        planibtout0_.finisheddate as finished3_23_,
        planibtout0_.finishedshiftid as finished4_23_,
        planibtout0_.itemid as itemid6_23_,
        planibtout0_.itemclassid as itemclas5_23_,
        planibtout0_.planfinishedgoodid as planfini7_23_,
        planibtout0_.planibtoutlotid as planibto8_23_,
        planibtout0_.planqty as planqty9_23_,
        planibtout0_.producerstoreid as produce10_23_,
        planibtout0_.sellerstoreid as sellers11_23_,
        planibtout0_.updateat as updatea12_23_,
        planibtout0_.updateby as updateb13_23_
    from
        planibtout planibtout0_
    where
        planibtout0_.producerstoreid=1117
        and planibtout0_.finisheddate=?
2563-04-10 12:19:03.359 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 ICT 1477]
2563-04-10 12:19:03.363 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.n.t.t.s.c.SellerStoreController - -Data Not Found- No record found in database
```

here is my .yml properties

```
    server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/xxx/

spring:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      username: xxx
      password: 
      continueOnError: false
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      minimum-idle: 0
      idle-timeout: 10000
      connection-timeout: 10000
      max-lifetime: 10000
      auto-commit: true

    jpa:
      show-sql: false
      hibernate:
        ddlAuto: none
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
          format_sql: true

startDayInWeek: 2

logging:
  level:
    com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig: DEBUG
    com.ntt.th: DEBUG
  pattern:
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
```

Comment: Add your controller pls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring data jpa findByDate is always returning an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733914/spring-data-jpa-findbydate-is-always-returning-an-empty-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no problem with `Date` binding that why query executed perfectly.
May be problem is Application Timezone and Database timezone is not matching.

You are sending `DATE` with IndoChina Timezone(ICT) `Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 ICT 1477` but you are using `serverTimezone=UTC`(In JDBC Url) for database which means you are using  UTC Timezone for Database.

So, you can change the timezone for database using `serverTimezone=ICT` to use IndoChina Timezone(ICT)

Comment: This is exactly the problem. last month I've got an error from SQLException about timeZone and I found a solution that I had to add the connection url params above which I had no idea how it works. so I changed serverTimeZone=Asia/Bankok and change local timezone on my machine and everything work just fine! Thank you so much.